# How isolated is pip/pipenv in a conda environment?

Tags: python, pip, conda, pipenv

Is it correct to expect a Conda environment to provide complete isolation and containment for pip/pipenv usage?

Let's say I create and activate a Conda environment and name it "pip-pip", then proceed with my project, which uses pipenv, while completely ignoring the fact that this is happening with a Conda environment activated.

1. Will all traces of that pipenv project be contained in "pip-pip", or is there a possibility of a spillover?
2. Will the fact that pip/pipenv is used from within "pip-pip" negatively affect the experience in any way?

Comment: Why don't you try it? It should take less than 10 minutes.

Comment: What would be a plan to cover all the edge cases?

Comment: The first step would be to identify the edge cases. Since they're not in the question, I assume that they are not identified. Anyway, If your environment was created in such a manner that it copied *Python* from *Anaconda* (instead being a pointer to it), point **#1.** should be covered. Regarding **#2.** depends what you understand by experience. If you created the env on a slower disk, then yes; otherwise it shouldn't make any difference. Normally (especially because of **#2.**), the question would be receiving close votes as being *Too Broad*.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

Identification of edge cases is the gist of my question :) .

Right now it seems like, provided you install pip in the environment, all effects of pip/pipenv are contained.

Due to limited personal experience, I may not have recognized a well-known issue or use case that I didn't even know how to Google, so it would be nice to know what *could* go wrong before it does.

Or, ideally, the answer would be "after the environment is destroyed - not a trace is left, and pip/pipenv doesn't see any difference when run from within a conda environment".

Answer (score 1):

This arrangement should work fine, as long as your shell and environment variables are configured correctly.

If you try to activate the Pipenv without the "Pip-pip" Conda environment active, you might have breakage or other unpredictable behavior, as Pipenv was installed with one Python and is being run with another. The extent of the breakage depends on the implementation details of Pipenv.

As a general rule, it should be possible to nest such "environment" programs arbitrarily, as long as they are well-designed, and as long as you activate the chain of environments in the order that they were originally installed. Whether this negatively affects your experience depends on your tolerance for annoyance.

However, Pipenv by default creates virtual environments in a global location. I'm not sure what that location is, but it's possible that you could end up with Pipenv environments installed alongside each other that depend on different Python versions. This, I think, might constitute "spillover" in the sense of your question.